# ListPlot with Uncertainties

Tags: plotting, around

How do I go about using `ListPlot` (or anything that allows me to make a basic graph and plot an exponential decay curve on it later) with uncertainties?

As a minimal example:

```
dataHist5 = {{Around[1.5, 1.5], Around[77.8, 8.8]}, {Around[19.5, 1.5],
     Around[63.5, 8.0]}, {Around[37.5, 1.5], 
    Around[63.8, 8.0]}, {Around[91.5, 1.5], Around[42.4, 6.5]}}
ListPlot[dataHist5]
```

This returns an empty graph with axes of 0 to 1 in both directions (I can attach a picture if desired but there's nothing to see).

I have been following the instructions on this page: https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/core-visualization/listplot-with-uncertainty.html

Am I missing something or am I misusing this function? Thanks for any help!

Edit: Added missing commas. Apparently this works for version 12, and my problem is I am using version 11

Comment: Looks like there are two commas missing in your list.

Comment: What version are you using? `Around` was introduced in version 12; in that version or newer your example works as expected once you have the commas to separate the value pairs, and not as you describe. Is `Around` black or blue in your MMA notebook?

Comment: Around is blue. This is MMA 11, So that would explain that pretty nicely. Is there of way of doing this in version 11? If it helps, all my x uncertainties are 1.5, and all my y uncertainties are just sqrt(y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is missing some commas

```
dataHist5 = {{Around[1.5, 1.5],Around[77.8, 8.8]} , {Around[19.5, 1.5],Around[63.5,8.0]} , {Around[37.5, 1.5],Around[63.8, 8.0]} , {Around[91.5, 1.5], Around[42.4, 6.5]}}
```

`ListPlot[dataHist5]`

[image]

Comment: You can to try put {1.5 \[PlusMinus] 1.5, 77.8 \[PlusMinus] 8.8} rather than "{Around[1.5, 1.5], Around[77.8, 8.8]}", but I don´t know if it works in MMA 11

Comment: It seems not to. It goes black rather than blue, but it doesn't seem to recognise it as an actual function. 1.5[PlusMinus] 1.5 for example tries to do 1.5*1.5.
Thank you for the help by the way, and the follow up

Comment: In V11 you can use the [ErrorBarPlots](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorListPlot.html) package.

Comment: Okay, this looks good and like what I might be after. Does MMa take into account the error bars when fitting a curve (as I'm hoping it does) or will it only fit around the points and just show error bars on top?